# Stored procedure from vb.net not working

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have created this stored procedure in Oracle 11g.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE LLENADO2 AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.LUNES=' ';

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.MARTES=' ';

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.MIERCOLES=' ';

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.JUEVES=' ';

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.VIERNES=' ';

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.SABADO=' ';

UPDATE TEMPORALREAL TR
SET TR.DOMINGO=' ';

FOR I IN (
SELECT NO,TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'DAY') AS DIA FROM ARCHIVO GROUP BY NO,    TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'DAY')
  ) LOOP

  IF I.DIA='LUNES    ' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.LUNES= 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO=I.NO;


  ELSIF  I.DIA='MARTES   ' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.MARTES = 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO=I.NO;


  ELSIF I.DIA='MIÉRCOLES' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.MIERCOLES= 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO =I.NO;


  ELSIF I.DIA='JUEVES   ' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.JUEVES = 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO= I.NO;

  ELSIF I.DIA='VIERNES  ' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.VIERNES = 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO= I.NO;

  ELSIF I.DIA='SÁBADO' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.SABADO = 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO = I.NO;

  ELSIF I.DIA='DOMINGO' THEN
  UPDATE TEMPORALREAL T
  SET T.DOMINGO = 'A'
  WHERE T.NUMERO_EMPLEADO = I.NO;

  END IF;
    END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  END LLENADO2;
```

When I execute this stored procedure from my SQL Developer it works fine, just update some data, but when I call the same stored procedure from VB.net, it just executes the first 7 updates but skips the for cycle that set an A into the columns lunes...viernes.

I have 8 more stored procedure working properly, this one is the only that does not work properly.

Here is the code I use on VB.net

```
    con.Open()
    Dim LLENADO2 As New OleDbCommand
    LLENADO2.Connection = con
    LLENADO2.CommandText = "LLENADO2"
    LLENADO2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    LLENADO2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wager that the `LOOP` is not being skipped.  I would wager that none of the `IF` or `ELSIF` statements evaluate to `true` when the procedure is called from your VB.net application because of differences in the NLS settings between the two environments.  I would guess that the VB.net application isn't set to default to Spanish.

My guess is that you want to ensure that Spanish language is used to convert the `datetime` to a day regardless of the session's language settings.  To do that, you'd want to explicitly specify the language in your `to_char`

```
TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Spanish')
```

I'd imagine that you really want to use the format mask `fmDAY` rather than `DAY` as well so that you don't have to include the extra spaces in your comparison strings.  Depending on the environment, you may want to get the day number rather than the day name since that is common across more NLS settings and clear to developers that may not speak Spanish.